# WCF Client Impersonation

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client, walkthrough

Can someone point me to a [relatively] simple walk-through on how to properly configure an ASP.Net hosted WCF 4.0 service to impersonate the credentials of a caller for just certain methods of the service, but allow anonymous access to other methods?

I've been reading a lot about this on MSDN, but the more I read, the more confused I get. Maybe I'm just a dunce, but this seems a lot harder than it should be :-(

I have looked through the posts here on SE, but none seem to point to an end-to-end sample or tutorial. There is a WCF guidance document on CodePlex, but it seems hopelessly out of date, and hasn't been updated since 2008.

Any help here would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via the [OperationBehaviorAttribute.Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.impersonation.aspx) property

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ISelectiveImpersonationExample
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ThisUsesImpersonation();

    [OperationContract]
    void ThisDoesNotUseImpersonation();
}


// Implementation
class SelectiveImpersonationExampleImpl : ISelectiveImpersonationExample
{
    [OperationBehavior(Impersonation=ImpersonationOption.Required)]
    public void ThisUsesImpersonation()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [OperationBehavior(Impersonation=ImpersonationOption.NotAllowed)]
    public void ThisDoesNotUseImpersonation()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Make sure that you do not set the service's behavior's [ImpersonateCallForAllOperations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceauthorizationbehavior.impersonatecallerforalloperations.aspx) value to true. If you do, the *ThisDoesNotUseImpersonation* function will throw an [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx).

I'm going on theory here, and haven't actually done it in real life. If it doesn't work please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. What I find most confusing, though, is trying to set the proper configuration settings to make this work. I'll let you know.